# HTK installing in windows10 / Not able to find VC98

Tags: visual-studio, installation, speech-recognition, htk

I am trying to install HTK Toolkit in my windows 10 machine.

It has a prerequisite of:
Ensure that your PATH contains C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\bin

I installed Microsoft Visual studios but I am not able to find the VC98 folder(file) in location where my visual studio is installed.

I tried to search it a lot of times, but still I was unsuccessful in finding it.

Can someone please solve this for me.

My final goal is to install HTK

Installing HTK on Microsoft Windows

Prerequisites

HTK has been verified to compile using Microsoft Visual Studio.

For testing, you will require a Perl interpreter such as ActivePerl.

You will need a tool such as 7-zip for unpacking the HTK source code archive.

Register on this site by accepting the HTK End User Licence Agreement, then download the latest HTK source code.

It is helpful if you have some familiarity with using the DOS command line interface, as you will need to interact with it in order to compile, install and run HTK.

Ensure that your PATH contains C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\bin
Compilation

Unpack the HTK sources using 7-zip.

Open a DOS command window: Click Start, select Run type cmd at the prompt and click OK.

cd into the directory in which you unpacked the sources.

cd into the htk directory. Type:

cd htk

Create a directory for the library and tools. Type:

mkdir bin.win32

Run VCVARS32 (it should be in your path, see prerequisites above)

Build the HTK Library, which provides the common functionality used by the HTK Tools. Enter the following commands:

cd HTKLib

nmake /f htk_htklib_nt.mkf all

cd ..

Build the HTK Tools

cd HTKTools

nmake /f htk_htktools_nt.mkf all

cd ..

cd HLMLib

nmake /f htk_hlmlib_nt.mkf all

cd ..

cd HLMTools

nmake /f htk_hlmtools_nt.mkf all

cd ..

Installation

The HTK tools have now been built and are in the bin.win32 directory. You should add this directory to your PATH, so that you can run them easily from the command line in future.

Comment: The "98" in "VC98" stands for 1998. You'll have a hard time finding Visual C++ version 6 nowadays, let alone getting it to install under Windows 10.

Comment: Oh! Actually I either need VC98 or .NET2003 but I cannot find any .NET in visual studio directory. Can you please tell me where is the .NET(Year Version)//bin is stored. Thank you for our support.

Comment: Visual Studio .NET 2003 was version 7.1, long gone. The current version is 14.2 a.k.a. Visual Studio 2019. You could try to use it, instead, though the compiler is several generations newer and may choke on some legacy code. To try it, open the "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019" which has the PATH (and all required environment) preset already.

Comment: I am still not able to get the path for any .NET in my file explorer. It just not present. can you please give an example by sharing your path. It would be helpful.

Comment: It's not just PATH that's needed, but also INCLUDE, LIB and others. The "Developer Command Prompt" takes care of all that housekeeping. Look for it in the start menu under the VS that you installed. For VS2019 for example the path would be something like `<vs-root>\vc\tools\msvc\<version>\bin\host<bitness>\<target-bitness>` but again it's not just the PATH that's needed.

Comment: Thanks but I am still not able to solve it. I went in a developer command prompt. But still, I was stuck. Can you please write a full fledge answer, So I can know the steps in a better way. My final aim is to use the command "run vscars" in command prompt as this is required to compile and run htk.

Comment: I am not familiar with the HTK toolkit, so I cannot help you with that. But if you meant `vcvars32.bat` (vc98) or `vsvars32.bat` (vs2003), those were the batch files to set the build environment. You can skip that step, since the Developer Command Prompt did that for you already.

Comment: I have edited the question. I am facing error in "run vcvars32" command. Please try to solve it.

Comment: `run vcvars32` Skip that step. Once you are in the Developer Command Prompt, all the required environment has been set up already. Go ahead and try the next step(s).

Comment: Okay, @dxiv brother. Thank you for your help. I am trying and will let you know the final results. Thanks.

Comment: nmake is not recognized as a internal or external command in cmd

Comment: That could indicate something is missing from your VS installation, and is not really related to HTK. First of all please make sure you can create and build a simple [C++ nmake-based](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/creating-a-makefile-project?view=vs-2019) Hello World project.

Comment: Yeah my c++ distribution was missing. I am downloading it right away.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Finally finished installing. I posted the answer with correct documentation. Hope it helps people

Comment: Glad it helped, and +1 for posting the answer for others who may be running into the same problems.

Comment: Thanks, this was my first question in this StackOverflow community. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing HTK:

I went through a very very tough time installing HTK on my computer.

This documentation will be helpful in installing it on any other computer.

Prequesities:

You should have a visual studio installed with c++ distribution. (Don’t just download MSVC). Download complete C++ distribution.

Download HTK Source code and HTK Samples.

Download and install Perl

Download any extracting software like( 7-zip)

Prior Steps:

Extract your HTK and HTK sample and keep it in two different directories. (Apart from each other)

Open VS and go on tool→ command line →  any command prompt(I selected Developer command prompt)

Installing steps 
cd into the directory in which you unpacked the sources.(source code and not the sample)
Execute the below commands one after the other.

cd htk

mkdir bin.win32

cd HTKLib

nmake /f htk_htklib_nt.mkf all

cd ..

Build the HTK Tools

cd HTKTools

nmake /f htk_htktools_nt.mkf all

cd ..

cd HLMLib

nmake /f htk_hlmlib_nt.mkf all

cd ..

cd HLMTools

nmake /f htk_hlmtools_nt.mkf all

cd ..

After this go to your bin.win32 folder and copy all the files to your

Sample directory inside HTKDemo.

cd into the directory HTKDemo and execute the command:

perl runDemo.pl configs/monPlainM1S1.dcf

Now you might find errors like hmm does not exist or such files does not exist when you execute this .

Just type mkdir (missing filename without parentheses)

And continue to do it until no errors are found

And soon you have reached the final stage : Success.

I know the documentation of current HTK is way too outdated and misleading but the 
stackoverflow community helped me to get through it.
I am attaching some links that might be helpful:

http://htk.eng.cam.ac.uk/docs/inst-win.shtml

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1092317&page=2

https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1522471.html

[HTK installing in windows10 / Not able to find VC98](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61765832/htk-installing-in-windows10-not-able-to-find-vc98)

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1522471